# how to get data in sql for a particular name or for all names in single query

Tags: mysql

I want this like

```
select * 
from tblcustomer 
where customername = 
        case when customername= 'ALL' then select * from tblcustomer 
                                      else select * 
                                            from tblcustomer 
                                            where customername = 'any string'
```

how to run this sql query . this shows error
this case shows you what i want but when i run this query it shows syntax error .
plz tell me the right way to use such case in where condition .

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Open any MySQL management tool (phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, ...) and copy/paste this query on the execute query page

Comment: this query shows error

Comment: Then you should probably share more details, like the error message and your attempts to resolve the error

Comment: Please share the error message, and your attempts to resolve the problem. Usually, a `CASE` should return a single value and not multiple ones

Answer (score 0):

Case statement will not work in this case. used the if condition as below.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GETCustomer

@CustomerName varchar(100)=null

AS
BEGIN
 
 
if @CustomerName = 'ALL'
    select * from tblcustomer
else
    select * from tblcustomer where customername = @customername
END
GO
```